# How do I iterate and remove elements from a list at the same time?

Tags: powershell

I am iterating through a list of strings and if the string is found in the hashtable then it is deleted from the list. I noticed some odd behavior. If I run the function twice more values are deleted out of on the list on the second run however, my understanding is that I should only need to run it once to delete all values that matched in the hashtable. Do I have my loop setup correctly?

Update: Thanks to the helpful comments I just copied any assets that did not match to the hashtable to a different list and returned it

```
function Compare()
{
param([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] $list,
      [Hashtable] $hashtable)
$listTwo = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]   
for($i=0; $i - lt $list.Count;$i++)
{
 if(($hashtable.$($list[$i])) -ne $null)
 {
 }
 else
 {
  $listTwo.Add($($list[$i])) 
 }
 }
 return $listTwo 
}
```

Comment: A trick: loop backwards

Comment: You could use a `Collections.Queue` maybe for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually not a good idea to remove elements from a list that you are iterating. A better idea would be to create another list and append elements to that list if they are not present in the hash table.

```
function Compare()
{
  param([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] $list,
        [Hashtable] $hashtable)

  return $list | Where-Object { -not $hashtable.ContainsKey($_) }
}
```

This method iterates the `list` and filters the elements by using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2).